# Jquery mobile, input field and tabletkeyboard num/alpha switching

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a website, with a standard input field.
Im running/have imported jquery UI + mobile UI.
Everything looks nice at my android tablet.

But i have this wierd issue, that is probably caused by Jquery mobile somehow:
I wanna type an item from my company witch could be "AA014TT55558"

When i switch to numeric keyboard and press 1 number, it switched back to alpha keyboard, why?

It dosnt happen at any other website iv tryed...

Thx

Comment: It seems like its the jquery .keyup function thats causes this problem, how come?

Answer (score 0):

Was caused by this, just if anyone else should face the same wierd thing:

```
<input class="class123" id="item1" />

$('#item1').keyup(function() {
   $('.class123').val($('#item1').val());
});
```

Somehow it makes atleast android keyboard to go wierdo